# Bootbox.prompt() set focus on text field

Tags: javascript, focus, bootbox

I can't seem to set the focus on Bootbox's textfield automatically.

here's my code:
     function setCode(myCode){

```
    bootbox.confirm("Enter your PIN: <input id='pin_code' type='password' name='pin_code'></input>", 
            function(result) {
                if(result)
                console.log($("#pin_code").val());
            });
        $("#pin_code").focus();
    };
```

Perhaps something about bootbox's code is getting in the way?

Comment: maybe you should accept correct answer...

Answer (score 5):

You can register a `shown` event handler that sets the focus (as suggested by @Shiny). However, as of Bootstrap 3 and Bootbox v4.x.x,  the shown event is namespaced and it is necessary to use the fully qualified name `shown.bs.modal` to register the event handler.  So the code would be:

```
var box = bootbox.confirm("Enter your PIN: <input id='pin_code' type='password' name='pin_code'></input>", 
    function(result) {
        if(result)
        console.log($("#pin_code").val());
    });

box.on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
  $("#pin_code").focus();
});
```

Trying to set the focus as you were doesn't work because the dialog isn't visible immediately after the call to `bootbox.confirm`. Elements that aren't visible can't have focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
var box = bootbox.confirm("Enter your PIN: <input id='pin_code' type='password' name='pin_code'></input>", 
        function(result) {
            if(result)
            console.log($("#pin_code").val());
        });
box.on('shown',function(){
    $("#pin_code").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old but check that if you're using Chrome, you don't have Dev Tools open.