# Focus on field doesn't work in a bootbox callback

Tags: jquery, bootbox

I have a field and a "check" button that checks if the field is empty. The problem is that after the click on 'Ok' in the popup (I use bootbox), it doesn't focus the field.

I tried with
`document.getElementById("field").focus();` 
and
 `$('#field').focus();`
but it doesn't works

http://jsfiddle.net/b4y40q5h/

Thanks

Comment: Yes. True. It doesn't work. Your code doesn't focus even if it sent through console. First mistake, **learn HTML**. It is not `></input>`, but `/>`.

Comment: Peculiar one! http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Lcv4c5ab/

Comment: You are right! I forgot it

Comment: I already answered [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657427/bootbox-prompt-set-focus-on-text-field/54442517#54442517](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657427/bootbox-prompt-set-focus-on-text-field/54442517#54442517)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin, after click "ok", modifies the dom and you loose the focus, so you only need a timeout to achieve it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4y40q5h/5/).

```
$("#btnCheck").click(function () {
    if ($('#field').val() == "")
    {
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "empty field",
            title: 'my site',
            buttons: {
                danger: {
                    label: 'ok',
                    className: "btn-primary",
                     callback: function () {
                         setTimeout(function(){
                             $('#field').focus();
                         }, 10);
                     }
                }
            }
        });
    }
else
    alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: Even this doesn't work buddy. Check out my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Lcv4c5ab/

Comment: Did you check the jsFiddle? .s

Answer (score 4):

Write this below script:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/b4y40q5h/6/)**

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.bootbox', function () {
   $('#field').focus();
});
```

Comment: Your solution is probably the most correct, but I have more fields and I prefer the solution with the timer..thank anyway!

Comment: @Pierminator.. Not a prob!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The other way is, using a `setTimeout`. I did it, but it didn't work for a reason, but now it works! God only knows why!

```
callback: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("F");
        $("#field").focus();
    }, 150);
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Lcv4c5ab/1/